# How to invoke a webservice using rest assured

Tags: java, web-services, maven, rest-assured

I am new to *Rest assured* and I am having troubles using it to run a basic program. I just created a Java project and added required rest assured jars.
Below is my simple code:

```
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import com.jayway.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.*;
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

public class RestServiceTest 
{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
//        RestAssured.baseURI="http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/";

          String str=RestAssured.get("http://restcountries.eu/rest/v1/name/Norway").asString();
          System.out.println(str);


    }
}
```

I have also added a pom.xml file to add following dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.9</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-external</artifactId>
  <version>1.9</version>
</dependency>
```

I am getting below exception when i ran the above code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.stdclasses.CachedSAMClass.getSAMMethod(CachedSAMClass.java:164)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.isSAM(ClassInfo.java:359)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.createCachedClass(ClassInfo.java:349)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.access$700(ClassInfo.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo$LazyCachedClassRef.initValue(ClassInfo.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo$LazyCachedClassRef.initValue(ClassInfo.java:488)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getCachedClass(ClassInfo.java:111)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:110)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$8.initValue(CachedClass.java:209)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$8.initValue(CachedClass.java:200)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getInterfaces(CachedClass.java:252)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.<init>(CachedClass.java:238)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.createCachedClass(ClassInfo.java:352)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.access$700(ClassInfo.java:41)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo$LazyCachedClassRef.initValue(ClassInfo.java:497)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo$LazyCachedClassRef.initValue(ClassInfo.java:488)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getCachedClass(ClassInfo.java:111)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ReflectionCache.getCachedClass(ReflectionCache.java:110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:180)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:216)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.<init>(MetaClassImpl.java:228)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createNormalMetaClass(MetaClassRegistry.java:171)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.createWithCustomLookup(MetaClassRegistry.java:161)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassRegistry$MetaClassCreationHandle.create(MetaClassRegistry.java:144)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(ClassInfo.java:253)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClass(ClassInfo.java:285)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MetaClassRegistryImpl.getMetaClass(MetaClassRegistryImpl.java:257)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getMetaClass(InvokerHelper.java:875)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.initMetaClass(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:825)
    at com.jayway.restassured.authentication.NoAuthScheme.$getStaticMetaClass(NoAuthScheme.groovy)
    at com.jayway.restassured.authentication.NoAuthScheme.<init>(NoAuthScheme.groovy)
    at com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured.<clinit>(RestAssured.java:317)
    at RestServiceTest.main(RestServiceTest.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 43 more
```

Can someone help do i need to create a maven project or simply java project and add pom.xml file?

I already added maven into environmental variables.

Comment: add dependency for rest-assured and httpclient along with your dependencies as suggested in my answer and you will be able to run the class and get the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to create a maven project and add dependencies to pom.xml file and build maven project.

other dependencies you need to add :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
    <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi dipali, i am having problems in configuring this as i am new to Java world and even i never worked on Maven. So far what i did was i downloaded, maven configured maven env.s, I have installed maven plugins for Eclipse. Can you please help me from here on to run the abouve just one line of code?

Comment: Take a look at this : http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-java-project-with-maven/

Comment: Dipali, i was never worked on maven and i explored maven and created a simple maven project and added this dependency       <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency> and ran the above my two lines of code. Thats it. Everything is working now. Just keeping here so anybody who references at later point, it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems that you're missing HTTP-Builder for Groovy.

If you're already using Maven, then try adding these lines to the "dependencies" section in your Maven pom.xml:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder/http-builder/0.6

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
    <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
    <version>0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Otherwise, download the .jar (same link) and add it to your project's class path.

See also the HTTP-Builder Wiki:

https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki

Comment: I included the jar and getting below exception: